# Python, MySQLConnector, MySQLCursor.fetchall() throws 'No result set' error, despite the query returning rows

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I have a simple Python 3 script, using MySQLConnector to access a database. Running the same query standalone (through PHPMyAdmin) returns the result I expect; a single row containing a user count. However when I execute my script, an exception is thrown as no results are returned.

My script:

```
     connection = self.Connect()

     cursor = connection.cursor()

     query = 'SELECT COUNT(UserName) FROM ig_UserAccounts WHERE UserName=\'TestUser\''

     cursor.execute(query)

     results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Exception message:

```
     mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

[Same query executed successfully in PHPMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUimu.png)

I verify the integrity of the database connection in the `self.Connect()` method like so, and have also tested it with `INSERT` statements to confirm that the connection works:

```
     try:
         connection = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.username, password=self.password, host=self.hostname, database=self.databaseName)

      except mysql.connector.Error as e:
          if e.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
              print("Invalid database username or password")
              return None

          elif e.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                 print("Invalid database name")
                 return None

          else:
              print(e)
              return None

      return connection
```

I've also tried using the `fetchone()` method in place of `fetchall()`, however this simply returns a None type.

Answer (score 0):

I've now resolved this issue, it seems to be a problem with debugging (in Visual Studio 2017). If I place a breakpoint early in the script and step over `execute()` and `fetchall()` line by line, the results set is emptied between lines.

However if I place a breakpoint only at the end of the script to pause execution, the results set is populated as expected.